# Are there any ATM's in Toronto where you can withdraw more than $400?

Tags: money, atms, toronto

I'm wandering about Toronto with my Mastercard which I can use to take out cash, and I have tried a few machines at Yonge and Bloor and they all first say they give $800 but then the ATM says it can only give out $400 max!  I'm lost. Do CIBC and RBC run the same?  I remember a while ago I could withdraw $700 from a Scotiabank. Was that a fluke? Now, is there any bank or specific ATM in downtown Toronto where one can take more than $400? I don't want to pay $10 fees trying to use the same machine several times at once. I still haven't figured out the limit at the non-bank ATM at the hotel.

Comment: This may be a limit imposed by the bank which issued your card. Especially if the local ATM says you can withdraw $800, but then later says only $400, it may be that your issuing bank has a $400 limit. Have you called your issuing bank to see what they can tell you?

Comment: The best solution would be to use a proper ATM card so you don't have to pay such high fees for each withdrawal, walk into a real bank to get cash in larger amounts, and/or use your credit card to pay for things directly.

Comment: It might have to do with the physical capabilities of the machine, as well.

Comment: @Flimzy Nope, no limit on my card!  Got $1000 at Scotiabank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope it's okay I answer my own question as it might be useful to others but I tried an ATM at Scotiabank and I was able to withdraw $1000. Not sure if it's that particular ATM or just that bank's machines but years earlier I renember being able to withdraw a large amount from SB as well.  Perhaps RBC and CIBC save their bills for everyone so the machines don't go empty but Scotiabank doesn't care?